# Angular testing with Karma and Jasmine, method utilizing HttpClient.get return undefined in the service spec, but returns data in the component

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular-httpclient

Angular service method that returns data from a database returns undefined in the testing spec

I have a method in myservice.ts called getEvents() that creates an array, call http.get method and fills the array, to return it with database information. However, when I call this method in my myservice.spec.ts file, it returns undefined.

myservice.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MyComponent } from './mycomponent.component.ts';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
    getEvents(): string[] {
        const events = [];
        this.http.get<MyClass[]>('http://localhost:3001/getEvents')
                 .subscribe(subscribedEvents => {
                    for (const event of subscribedEvents ) {
                        events.push(event);
                    }
                 });
        return events;
    }
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

myservice.service.spec.ts:

```
import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MyService } from './myservice.service';

describe('MyService', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [ HttpClientModule ],
          providers: [ MyService ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
      }));
  it('getEvents', () => {
    const service: MyService = TestBed.get(MyService);
    expect(service.getEvents()[0]).toEqual('FirstEvent');
  });
});
```

getEvents() makes a call to my backend server (verified by the component and by Postman), takes the data from .subscribe(), and places that into an array. The filled array gets returned.
This works fine in my component, but in the service spec, it returns undefined.

I apologize for the generic names; I do not want my original code posted.

Error:

```
Expected undefined to equal 'FirstEvent'.
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to test here ? Do you want to make a real http call ? Or mock the answer ?

Also your service should return an observable because here the method getEvents will return `events = [];`  i.e. an empty array the array will only be filled when the observable is subscribed.

So MyService::getEvents should return an observable and you will subscribe it in your component.

Then to test it you should mock/spy MyService::getEvents so it does not make a real http call

Comment: I was trying to make a real call and confirm that there is definitely data coming in. I don't understand why my method would return [] here, yet it returns data when the component gets rendered.

Comment: We use a HttpTestingController instead of real backend to stimulate a response.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, we do not use real backend to get a response while testing, instead we use HttpTestingController to stimulate it. The test of your sample service can be something like below;

```
 it('should return events', async(inject([MyService, HttpTestingController],
    (service: MyService, httpMock: HttpTestingController) => {
      // Arrange
      let endResponse;
      const feedEvent = { sth : '1234' };
      // Act
      service.getEvents().subscribe(result => {
        // Assert
        endResponse = result;
      });
      const request = httpMock.expectOne((req: HttpRequest<any>) => {
        return req.method === 'GET'
      }, `get event`);
      // Assert
      request.flush({ sth: '1234' });
      expect(endResponse).toEqual(feedEvent);
    })));
```